# Why is Python returning None if the input before the accepted input is incorrect?

Tags: python, return-value

The Python code:

```
def force_input(type):
    try:
        return type(input())
    except ValueError:
        print(f'Input must be {type}')
        force_input(type)

number = force_input(int)
print(number)
```

For example, if I enter lettuce I get `Input must be <class 'int'>` as expected.
But then when I enter a integer like 9, I get `None` instead of 9. The code works fine if I enter an integer first, but not if the input is incorrect. Why is this?

Comment: Using recursion for this task is the wrong approach. You might want to read: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 0):

In the event that `type(input())` raises a `ValueError` exception, you have no explicit return in your exception handling code. In the absence of an explicit return, Python functions return `None`.

You need to return the result of your recursive call. Otherwise, the function *is* called again, but the `return` in the recursive call does not return from the caller.

```py
def force_input(type):
    try:
        return type(input())
    except ValueError:
        print(f'Input must be {type}')
        return force_input(type)
```

Note that a recursive function is not very Pythonic in this scenario. It would be more typical to see an explicit while loop.

```py
def force_input(type):
    while True:
        try:
            return type(input())
        except ValueError:
            print(f'Input must be {type}')
```